# Python copiando una columna de un .txt a un .csv, problemas con los decimales

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Estoy creando un arreglo numpy que se llama tabla, en la quinta columna quiero guardar una lista de números que tengo en un archivo .txt

Lo hago con el siguiente código:

```
tabla[:, 4] = np.fromfile('/home/lucia/Documentos/Base de datos de imagenes/TID2013/mos.txt', sep='\n')
```

en el archivo most.txt se encuentra una lista de 3000 números, uno debajo del otro, osea organizado como una columna, los números varían de 0 a 9 y tienen 5 dígitos decimales, la lista se ve algo así:

```
5.51429
5.56757
4.94444
4.37838
3.86486
.
.
.
```

Una vez que tengo mi tabla completa (las otras columnas ahora no interesan), quiero guardarla en un archivo .csv (comma separated values), lo hago con el siguiente código:

```
a=tabla.tolist()

with open('tabla.csv', 'w') as csvfile:  
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

El problema es que a los números mos que tienen, la parte entera distinta de 0, los dos últimos dígitos decimales igual a 0 y el tercero distinto de 0 los guarda sin el punto, así por ejemplo, a 3.92500 lo guarda como 3925 a 6.12500 lo guarda como 6125, es decir, parece que toma el punto como si fueran miles y no decimales...

¿Alguien tiene idea de por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: si le das  `print a` después del  `a=tabla.tolist()`, te marca los decimales?

Comment: Si, parece que el problema aparece cuando lo guarda en el .csv

Comment: fijate el formato, por defecto ignoraria los ceros que se encuentren a la derecha de manera que deberias ser mas explicito con algo como ('%.5f') % n para que mantenga el punto y los 5 decimales despues del mismo, probablemente tengas que hacer eso a la hora de escribir el CSV... "explicito es mejor que implicito"

Comment: una vez generado con que abres tu csv?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez has dado en el clavo.... Ese es el problema real, el csv se genera correctamente, basta con usar un editor de texto plano para abrir el csv para darse cuenta. No es un problema de creación del csv sino del programa que usas para interpretarlo que entiende que el punto es un separador de miles y no un punto decimal (notación inglesa).

Comment: con excel de linux lo abro, osea libre office... cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todos los números tienen 5 decimales podrías formatearlo de la siguiente manera:

```
a = tuple([format(x, '.5f') for x in y] for y in tabla.tolist())

with open('tabla.csv', 'w') as csvfile:  
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

De esa manera se fuerza el formato a 5 decimales '.5f' usando un generator expression para crear una nueva tupla.

Comment: Genial! Esto es lo que más me convence :)

Answer (score 1):

**El csv generado es correcto**, el código funciona como debe, de hecho no hace falta pasar ni siquiera a una lista los datos, acepta el array como tal (`writer.writerows(tabla)`). El problema no es de Python sino del **programa o método que usas para abrir el csv** generado que **está interpretando el punto como separador de miles**. Abrelo con un editor de texto plano y te darás cuenta de esto.

Para solucionarlo depende del programa/método que uses para abrir el csv, en el caso de ***LibreOffice*** basta con seleccionar *"Inglés (EE.UU)"* como idioma de importación para que interprete perfectamente los decimales.

Simulando tu código:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#Simulamos un array acorde a tu ejemplo
tabla = np.zeros((7, 5))
tabla[:, 4] = [5.51429, 5.56757, 4.94444, 4.37838, 3.86486, 3.92500, 6.12500]


headers = ('Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5')

with open('tabla.csv', 'w') as csvfile:  
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(tabla)
```

La **salida real** es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves no hay ningún problema, el problema está en el programa que usas para abrir el csv y como lo interpreta.

Ya que usas NumPy puedes seguir usandolo para guardar el csv mediante [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) si lo deseas:

```
import numpy as np

#Simulamos un array acorde a tu ejemplo
tabla = np.zeros((7, 5))
tabla[:, 4] = [5.51429, 5.56757, 4.94444, 4.37838, 3.86486, 3.92500, 6.12500]


headers = 'Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5'
formato = ['%.1f', '%.1f', '%.1f', '%.1f', '%.5f']
with open ("tabla.csv", 'wb') as csvfile:
    np.savetxt(csvfile, tabla, delimiter=",", fmt=formato, newline='\r\n', header=headers, comments='')
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes jugar con los formatos para obtener la salida que desees, en este caso todas las columnas tienen un decimal en el csv menos la 5 (índice 4) que tiene 5 decimales.

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema que veo es `np.fromfile()` no te sirve para leer un archivo CSV sino para un archivo previamente salvado mediante `data.tofile()`. Si va a usar numpy para la lectura, te recomiendo hacer algo así:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
```